# Broken Age - How to Access Backer Content if missed campaign?

Tags: broken-age

How can one access the backer content for Broken Age, if they missed the original Kickstarter campaign?

As seen here http://www.doublefine.com/dfa

Looks like they had a 'Slacker Backer' option, but no longer available.

The content includes lots of interesting behind the scenes stuff like character design, programming challenges, production updates oh gosh it hurts to write all this stuff sob!!!

Answer (score 2):

From [the site](http://www.doublefine.com/dfapay):

"Broken Age backer access is no longer available to buy!

If you're already a backer, head over to the backer content page to browse all the documentary episodes and development updates.

If you're not, don't worry—the game will be out soon for everyone to play!"

So, looks like you are out of luck.

Comment: Yeah I saw that. But was wondering if the backer content is purchasable? Doesn't look like it comes with the game

Comment: They likely wanted to keep it as backer only content, otherwise there is no point in backing it beforehand if you can just get the stuff after.